# PHP is_int is not performing as expected

Tags: php, isinteger

I have a page (index.php) that takes a `GET` variable from the URL and checks it for security purposes.  This `GET` variable should only be an integer.  I am using the following code to check this, but in all instances, integer or not, I get the index.php page.  The header never appears.  After this code, the rest of the page appears starting with the `html` tag.

PHP:

```
<?php ob_start(); session_start();
$q=trim($_GET['q']);
if (!is_numeric($q)){
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't know if you're aware already, but you should add an `exit();` after the `header(..)`. Otherwise the script will continue to print out the page contents.

Comment: Reading [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) would show you, that `is_int()` checks the type of the variable, so string with "`123`" into `is_int()` will not return `true`, as this is string. Also why did you tag your post with `http-status-code-404`?

Comment: @Tadeck tag removed.  thank you for that documentation.  im now using is_numeric and it still isnt working

Comment: @amir75 you are right.  it worked! is it ok if i use `die();` instead?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It won't be an integer if it's passed in a query string.

Try `is_numeric()`

Comment: Also `ctype_digit()` for a string that consists only of numbers.

Comment: @alien I have updated my current code and i get the same behavior as before :[

Comment: Try changing `ob_start;` to `ob_start();`

Comment: @AlienWebguy when i substitute `die("test")` for the header it works perfectly.  There must be something wrong with my header.  Do i have to set up a 404 page on my server?

Comment: You can do so easily in your .htaccess with: `ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html`

Comment: @maohieng because numbers passed in query strings are literally strings. `is_int(123) // true` `is_int('123') // false` `is_numeric(123) // true` `is_numeric('123') // true`

Answer (score 5):

There is a better way to do this, which is casting to int:

```
$q = (int) $_GET['q'];
```

The is_int *is* behaving as expected. Because GET arguments are always strings. Try var_dumping them.

Comment: Come to think of it, AlienWebguy's answer is probably better as you'll be able to filter out any 'weird' values...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to validate input which should be number but in `$_GET` or `$_POST` you will get it as string. `is_numeric()` may be problematic, because it allows hex, binary and octal format (from manual):

`Thus +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value. Hexadecimal (e.g. 0xf4c3b00c), Binary (e.g. 0b10100111001), Octal (e.g. 0777) notation is allowed too but only without sign, decimal and exponential part.`

You can't use `is_int()` as it's only for integer values (not string!) so... You can validate numbers which are string AND integer that way:

```
/**
 * Validate integer.
 */
class IntegerValidator
{
    /**
     * Run validation.
     * @param string $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isIntVal(string $value): bool
    {
        if (!self::hasValidIntegerFormat($value)) {
            return false;
        }

        return !self::hasLeadingZero($value);
    }

    /**
     * Check if given string looks like valid integer. Negative numbers allowed.
     * @param string $value
     * @return bool
     */
    private static function hasValidIntegerFormat(string $value): bool
    {
        return (bool) preg_match('/^-?[0-9]+$/', $value);
    }

    /**
     * Check if given number has leading 0. Thus it's invalid integer.
     * @param string $number
     * @return bool
     */
    private static function hasLeadingZero(string $number): bool
    {
        return self::extractFirstDigit($number) === 0;
    }

    /**
     * Extract first digit from given number.
     * @param string $number
     * @return int
     */
    private static function extractFirstDigit(string $number): int
    {
        return self::isNegativeInteger($number)
            ? (int) $number[1]
            : (int) $number[0];
    }

    /**
     * Check if number is negative integer. ie. starts with minus sign on the beginning.
     * @param string $number
     * @return bool
     */
    private static function isNegativeInteger(string $number): bool
    {
        return $number[0] === '-';
    }
}

var_dump(IntegerValidator::isIntVal('123'));   // true
var_dump(IntegerValidator::isIntVal('0123'));  // false
var_dump(IntegerValidator::isIntVal('-0123')); // false
var_dump(IntegerValidator::isIntVal('-123'));  // true
```

It is also possible to override is_int() function, using [override_function()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) but it still may be useful in original version.